# Reaction of cyclohexene with HCO3H

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Reaction of cyclohexene with a peroxy acid like mCPBA gives an epoxy acid according to Prilezhaev Reaction.
I think it should work with any per acid according to the [Mechanism here](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/prilezhaev-reaction.shtm). But HCO3H gives anti diols, as given in my textbook.
Is hydrolysis of epoxide going on?

Comment: $\ce{H2CO3}$ is not a peracid.

Comment: @Maurice  I think the OP is refering to performic acid as epoxidation reagent

Comment: @OscarLanzi  performic acid is moderately oil-soluble according to this paper  https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.iecr.1c02212

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this [patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2745848A/en)

> Performic acid is unsatisfactory as an epoxidizing agent for cyclohexene because the reaction leads preferentially to hydroxy-formoxy cyclohexane with small amounts and thus very low yields of the desired cyclohexene oxide.

So the initial nucleophilic species is formate anion which will readily hydrolyse in work-up

Answer (score 5):

If making [cyclohexene oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclohexene_oxide) is desired, there are better methods than trying performic acid with its potential side reaction(s). The Wikipedia article suggests:

- Industrially, using a heterogeneously catalyzed reaction, such as combining cyclohexene with oxygen on silver.
- In the laboratory, using magnesium monoperoxyphthalate, $\ce{Mg^{2+}}\ce{[o-C6H4(CO2^-)(C(O)O2^-)]}$, as the active oxygen source.